# Current density vector clarification

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, electric-current, charge, conductors

I have some basic doubts about current density vector $\vec J$, which is defined as "the vector whose magnitude is the electric current density, and whose direction is the same as the motion of the positive charges" (Source: Wikipedia).

Let's consider a cylindrical conductor like this:

[image]

Current may be found through this formula, as you know:

$\vec I = \int \vec{J} \cdot \hat n  dA$.

Since there is the scalar product, to define current we consider only the charges that are flowing in the direction orthogonal to the transverse section of the conductor.

My questions are:

1. Why do we ignore charges that flow in other directions in the definition of current? Isn't their motion a current?
2. If a voltage source is connected with its terminals to A and B, so there will be a voltage gradient only along the cylindrical axis, will there be a reason for charge to flow in other directions (in addition to the cylindrical axis)? Or will $\vec J$ be always parallel to the conductor cylindrical axis?
3. What is the meaning of a current density component flowing for instance upward in the picture? Which may be its cause if voltage is applied only between A and B? For instance an incident electromagnetic wave? For the continuity equation, I'd say that it results in charge accumulation on the conductor surface, since that charge cannot go outside the conductor, since it is vacuum (or dielectric).
4. Suppose current flows only from A and B, so along the cylindrical axis, and suppose the conductor to be like a circular crown cylinder (like the shield of a coaxial cable) with very very small thickness. Since its thickness is small, we may think that charges flow only on the conductor surface. Is this charge the accumulated surface charge that appears in the conductor boundary condition ($\ E = \frac\sigma { \epsilon} $)? Or is this last one determined only by the charge that is accumulated by a current density component which is orthogonal to the conductor surface?